# Improve an array division base on it's element

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I want to divide an array into two array based on it's elements
for example if I have this array as input

```
[{id:1,name:"item1_g1"},{id:2,name:"item2_g2"},{id:3,name:"item3_g1"},{id:2,name:"item4_g2"}]
```

the output should be two arrays like this

first array:

```
[{id:1,name:"item1_g1"},{id:3,name:"item3_g1"}]
```

second array:

```
[{id:2,name:"item2_g2"},{id:2,name:"item4_g2"}]
```

As you I just need to group elements based on their attribute `name`

I am using angularjs and I alreayd tried this code

```js
var values = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "item1_g1"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "item2_g2"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "item3_g1"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "item4_g2"
}];
var group1 = values.filter(function(item) {
  return (item.name.includes('g1'));
});
var group2 = values.filter(function(item) {
  return (item.name.includes('g2'));
});
console.log(group1, group2)
```

But I didnt like this solution because in case I have a heavy array then I need to loop it n times in order to extract n arrays which is not good for performance

Is there a way to make all of this in one loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through the array just once, use criteria to decide which array an item should be put into. For example:

```js
var values = [
  { id: 1, name: "item1_g1" }, 
  { id: 2, name: "item2_g2" }, 
  { id: 3, name: "item3_g1" }, 
  { id: 2, name: "item4_g2" }
];

const [group1, group2] = values.reduce((groups, el) => {
   groups[1^el.name.includes('g1')].push(el);  
   return groups;
}, [[], []]);
  
console.log(group1, group2);
```

You can create a more generic grouping function, that takes two arguments - array of items to sort and predicate function (which returns an index). That'll be a bit more wordy though:

```
function groupBy(arr, indexer) {
  return arr.reduce((groups, el) => {
    const index = indexer(el);
    groups[index] = groups[index] || [];
    groups[index].push(el);
    return groups;
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I exactly want

Answer (score 1):

You can loop only one time using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) combined with [String.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/slice)

Code example:

```js
const values = [{id: 1,name: "item1_g1"}, {id: 2,name: "item2_g2"}, {id: 3,name: "item3_g1"}, {id: 2,name: "item4_g2"}];
const groups = values.reduce((a, c) => (a[c.name.slice(-2)].push(c), a), {g1: [], g2: []});

console.log(groups);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one loop as below :

```
var values = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "item1_g1"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "item2_g2"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "item3_g1"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "item4_g2"
}];
let group1 = [];
let group2 = [];
values.forEach( item => {
    if(item.name.includes('g1')){
       group1.push(item);
    } else {
       group2.push(item);
    }
})
console.log(group1)
console.log(group2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// I would do this the old fashioned way. 
// iterate over values and add them to a map with same group id
// this way you won't need to worry about how many groups you have


var groups = {};
for(i=0;i<values.length;i++){
    var groupNum = values[i].name.substring(values[i].name.indexOf('_g') + 2);
    if(groups[groupNum]){
        groups[groupNum].push(values[i]);
    }
    else {
        groups[groupNum] = [values[i]];
    }
}

console.log(groups);
{
  "1": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "item1_g1"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "item3_g1"
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "item2_g2"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "item4_g2"
    }
  ]
}"
```

Comment: this is an optimum way. Now you convert this code using declarative programming methods like reduce, filter or whatever looks good to you.